# Dynamically accessing class instance properties in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to make class methods act as socket events, and for that I need to be able dynamically access these. I am using `keyof` to indicate that the string should be a key of the instance. `this[keyof this]` is however not recognized as a function type for some reason:

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'this[keyof this]' is not assignable to
> parameter of type '(...args: any[]) => void'.   Type 'this[string] |
> this[number] | this[symbol]' is not assignable to type '(...args:
> any[]) => void'.
> Type 'this[string]' is not assignable to type '(...args: any[]) => void'.

```
class Events extends SocketListener {
  private events: string[]
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.events = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Events.prototype)
      .filter(event => event !== 'constructor' && event[0] !== '_')
  }

  _registerEvents(socket: Socket) {
    _.each(this.events, (event) => {
      socket.on(event, this[event as keyof this])
    })
  }
  
  message(msg: string) {
    console.log(`Socket msg: ${msg}`)
  }
}
```

Comment: May I know what's the signature of `socket.on` function?

Comment: @Nishant eventName (String), callback (Function) - Returns Socket